# How to create and sign in users using FactoryGirl + omniauth-identity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, factory-bot

I implemented [omniauth-identity](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity) following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity).

So I ended up with something like this:

**identity.rb:**

```
class Identity < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || create_with_omniauth(auth)
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    end
  end
```

**schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "identities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    :null => false
    t.boolean  "admin",      :default => false
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
  end
```

Now, I'm not very sure how to create users with [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) since the password is being handled by the `Identity` model.

I can create users if I omit the password, but without a password, I can't sign them in.

I really don't know how to make this thing work. Is there a common solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issues and so I tested a little bit. FactoryGirl actually does encrypt the password in my case (Mongoid) and so it came down to just store the cleartext-password for later retrieval:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :local_identity do

    #snip

    sequence :password do |n|
      "MyPassword#{n}"
    end
  end
end
```

It can be used like this (note the password_digest in the third line):

```
i = FactoryGirl.build(:local_identity)
i.password # MyPassword1
Bcrypt::Password.new(i.password_digest) == i.password # true
```